How to setup analytics of total number of documents in subcollections with Firebase
I have what is essentially an advanced note-taking app where users create different types of notes. I would love to setup some analytics in Firebase analytics so I can view graphs of total counts for the different types of notes across all users. Or even if I can't setup a graph easily, I would like to be able to manually query to determine this.
The structure of my firestore db is essentially like:
usersCollection > userDocument > notesCollection > noteDocument
I would like to do a count of the size of notesCollection across all users in the users collection. I.e. if Alice has 3 notes, Bob has 2 notes, and Charlie has 5 notes, I want to get back that there are 10 total notes.
Is there a way to do this from within firebase analytics, or something else in the firebase / google cloud console?


Is there a way to do this from within firebase analytics, or something else in the firebase / google cloud console?

No.  You're going to have to write some code to perform the necessary queries to create this report.  A collection group query on notesCollection with a count aggregation will likely do what you want.
